# Estimator when a coin is either fair or has two heads

Tags: maximum-likelihood

Suppose that $X_1,\dots,X_n$ are independent and identically distributed such that $X_1\sim\text{Bernoulli}(\theta)$.

If $\theta\in\{1/2,1\}$, find the maximum likelihood estimator of $\theta$. Show that this estimator is biased, but it's asymptotically unbiased.

Answer (score 1):

The likelihood function is
$$
  L(\theta\mid x_1,\dots,x_n) = \theta^{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i} (1-\theta)^{n-\sum_{i=1}^n x_i}.
$$
The maximum likelihood estimator is
$$
  \hat{\theta}=\hat{\theta}(X_1,\dots,X_n)=
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{2} &\text{if} &\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\ne n; \\
1 &\text{if} &\sum_{i=1}^n X_i=n.
\end{cases}
$$
Hence,
$$
  \mathbb{E}_\theta[\hat{\theta}]=
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{2}\left(1-\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n\right) + \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n &\text{if} &\theta=\frac{1}{2}; \\
1 &\text{if} &\theta=1.
\end{cases}
$$
Therefore,
$$
  \text{Bias}_\theta[\hat{\theta}]=
\begin{cases}
\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n-\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n+1} &\text{if} &\theta=\frac{1}{2}; \\
0 &\text{if} &\theta=1;
\end{cases}
$$
and the estimator is biased. But it's asymptotically unbiased, since
$$
  \text{Bias}_\theta[\hat{\theta}] \to 0
$$
when $n\to\infty$, for $\theta\in\{1/2,1\}$.

Comment: Is doing your homework on SE the new thing?

Comment: No, it's an old thing: https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer